# ¿Cómo sumar precios de checkboxes seleccionados con c#? windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

alguien sabe como puedo declarar la variable de precio en checkboxes y luego hacer que al seleccionar los checkboxes se sume el total y aparezca como un messagebox? No es con base de datos, es un windows form c#.

El código que tengo para cada checkbox es:

```
    private void chckghost_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chckghost = new CheckBox();
        chckghost.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        chckghost.AutoCheck = false;
        Controls.Add(chckghost);
    }
```

y tengo el contador de check boxes como:

```
    int contador = 0;
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            if ((control as CheckBox).Checked == true) ;
            {
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Entonces quiero saber cómo declarar los precios y hacer que se sumen

Comment: Hola, intenta poner el ejemplo de codigo que tienes para poderte ayudar, recuerda que es mas facil para podernos contextualizar

Comment: Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @KevinRestrepo gracias ;( ya puse un ejemplo de como tengo el código

Comment: no entiendo tu problema.. no te esta contando los checkbox? los estas creando cada vez que apretas otro checkbox? porque no llevas la cuenta de checkbox, guardandolos en un array de checkbox y luego recorriendolo directamente? un checkbox es una clase como cualquier otra...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

entendiendo lo que explicas al inicio, me supongo que quieres sumar el valor predeterminado de cada elemento checkbox dentro del form.cs, si ese es el caso esto te puede servir:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int valorCB1 = 10;
        int valorCB2 = 20;
        int valorCB3 = 30;
        int suma = 0;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
            

        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                suma = suma + valorCB1;

                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Valor de la suma " + lblPrecio.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                suma = suma - valorCB1;
                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
            }
        
            
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                suma = suma + valorCB2;

                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Valor de la suma " + lblPrecio.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                suma = suma - valorCB2;
                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                suma = suma + valorCB3;

                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Valor de la suma " + lblPrecio.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                suma = suma - valorCB3;
                lblPrecio.Text = suma.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: En realidad..no.. fijate que esta creando checkbox en tiempo de ejecucion y por eso esta haciendo un foreach control al final... aunque esto soluciona el tema si tuvieras varios checkbox fijos, igual es una mala solucion porque se puede solucionar con un solo metodo, ya que sender es el tipo de control que te dice que checkbox lo mando a ejecutar, con lo cual todo tu codigo es resumible a un solo metodo.

Comment: @gbianchi Tienes razón